# How do I access the item of a ItemsControl's item bound to a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, itemscontrol

(I'm struggling to clearly ask my question, sorry if it's not clear.)

I want to access the item of an ItemsControl that is bound to a UserControl, but I don't know what property it is bound to. Here's an example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Widgets}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:WidgetView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

where "Widgets" is a collection of the following class instances:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public int OtherData { get; set; }
    public Widget() {}
}
```

and "WidgetView" is a UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.WidgetView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp">
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Content="Set Other Data" Click="btn_clicked"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</UserControl>
```

with code-behind:

```
public partial class WidgetView : UserControl
{
    public WidgetView() {}
    private void btn_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (???).OtherData = 42;
    }
}
```

In the code-behind, how would I access the "Widget" instance the "WidgetView" is bound to in the ItemsControl?

Comment: Ideally your button would bind to a Command which would receive the view model or some portion of it as the parameter. Do you know what I mean by that?

Comment: @Crowcoder Somewhat, though how would I access the "OtherData" member? I'm fairly new to WPF, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Crowcoder said; you would typically do this via `ICommand` and not have the code-behind involved.

That being said; for the few times you *need* this method you access it via `DataContext`. That's an object, so you'll need to cast:

```
private void btn_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var widget = (Widget)DataContext; //Or a safer cast!
         widget.OtherData = 42;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried casting the DataContext, but an exception is thrown because it's null.

Comment: Wait a minute, disregard my prior comment, that works.

Comment: My problem with DataContext being null was trying to access it in the constructor of UserControl. I guess that it is set by ItemsControl _after_ the UserControl is created. Fixed by using the "Loaded" event to access the DataContext.